# how to read whole binary file with WINAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a task to save structure to binary file and then print out the file to console. Data is being written to a file, but when I read it I get output only first word. I guess I'm missing something in my code. Will appreciate your help.

```
struct Book
{
  char bookName[40];
  char author[40];
  float rating;
};

Book book;

int bookAmount  = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < bookAmount; i++){
  cout << "Book Name: ";
  cin >> book.bookName;

  cout << "Book Author: ";
  cin >> book.author;

  cout << "Rating: ";
  cin >> book.rating;

   DWORD dwBytesWritten;
   BOOL writeFile = WriteFile(hFile, &book, sizeof(book), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
}
DWORD numberOfBytesToRead;
char buff[255];

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("file.dat", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
BOOL readFile = ReadFile(hFile, &buff, sizeof(book), &numberOfBytesToRead, NULL);

  if (readFile != 0) {

    while (numberOfBytesToRead != 0) {
      cout << buff << endl;
      ReadFile(hFile, &buff, sizeof(book), &numberOfBytesToRead, NULL);
    }

  }
```

Comment: `numberOfBytesToRead` is number of bytes successfully read. "to read" is the 3rd parameter.

Comment: The `>>` operator only reads single words - you want std::getline.

Comment: Any special reason why you want to use the WinAPI for this? The standard C++ classes would probably do very nicely.

Comment: It should go without saying that you shouldn't using a stream's `operator>>` to read into a fixed-sized buffer.  The best case scenario is that it segfaults.  Either read in using [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), or store your data in a `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BOOL readFile = ReadFile(hFile, &buff, sizeof(book), &numberOfBytesToRead, NULL);
cout << buff << endl;
```

You are reading to a `char[255]`, not a `Book` structure. Hence the title of the book ends with an \0, that's why only that is printed. `cout` operates on a char array, not on the structure.

Bad way to store/receive data btw. Prone to security issues.

Comment: so instead of `char buff[255]`, i need to read i to `book` structure and then just iterate over `book` struct

Comment: @Andrew You wrote a `book`, you should read a `book`. Why do anything else?